# ServiceStack SelectLazy<long> System.NullReferenceException

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

```
            using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection()) {
            List<long> x = db.SelectLazy<long>(
                "SELECT Id FROM MyTable").ToList();
            }
```

Why is x null?

It works when I use Select instead of SelectLazy, or when I use SelectLazy on the entire row and not just the Id.

Answer (score 2):

In OrmLite you use different API's to match the results you're after, e.g:

- `Select*` API's for returning a `List<MyTable>`
- `Column*` API's for returning a column of field values, e.g `List<long>`
- `Single*` API's for returning a Single Row, e.g `Table`
- `Scalar*` API's for returning a Single field value, e.g `long`

So to select a column as a List of fields you use `db.Column`, e.g:

```
var results = db.Column<long>(db.From<MyTable>().Select(x => x.Id));
```

These also have Raw `Sql*` equivalents, e.g:

```
var results = db.SqlColumn<long>("SELECT Id FROM MyTable");
```

Comment: Are there lazy loading methods for Column/SqlColumn? Also how exactly does SelectLazy work? What sql query does it generate?

Comment: @user3099705 there isn't yet. Here's the [impl for SelectLazy](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/73751a53d833f4d67ebba7d8418590da66581ad2/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteReadExtensions.cs#L448). It uses the same SQL query, just lazily fetches each row from the data reader as needed.

Comment: @user3099705 I've just added support for [db.ColumnLazy in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/a0c7984c4c22ed8a495740afc49feedcdfc1c653) available from **v4.0.31+** that's [now deployed to MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).